# Mysql REGEXP select numbers starting with given digit(s)

Tags: mysql, regex

my table has a column with comma-separated (and eventually a space, too) numbers; those numbers can have from five to twelve digits.

```
9645811, 9646011,9645911, 9646111
```

or

```
41031, 41027, 559645811, 5501006009
```

I need to select the rows with that column containing a number STARTING with given digits. In the above examples, only the first has to be selected. What I've tried so far:

```
SELECT myfield FROM mytable
WHERE myfield REGEXP ('(^|[,\s]+)(96458[\d]*)([,\s]*|$)');
```

However the query returns no results. I'd like to select only the first row, where there is a number STARTING with 96458.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: your regex seems ok.

Comment: `WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(myfield ,',',1) LIKE '96458%'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a starting word boundary `[[:<:]]`:

```
SELECT myfield FROM mytable WHERE myfield REGEXP ('[[:<:]]96458');
```

See the [MySQL regex syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) for more details.

> `[[:<:]], [[:>:]]`
>
> These markers stand for word boundaries. They match the beginning and end of words, respectively.

See this [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f97d8/1).